# Scrolling Webelement using Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Please help me to handle StaleElementReferanceException.
I am trying to scroll a webelement  using action class.
Below is the code:

```
public void newsSearch() throws StaleElementReferenceException{

    driver.get("https://pi.persistent.co.in");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("ui-accordion-1-header-2")).click();

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    int numOfPixels = 2;
    WebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-accordion-1-panel-2']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"));

    for (int i = 2; i < 50; i = i + numOfPixels) {

        act.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, numOfPixels).release().perform();
        System.out.println("Inside for loop");

    }
    System.out.println("After for loop");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ulNotification']/li[5]/h3")).click();
    driver.close();
}
```

It is giving an Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 30.16 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'BHD22524', ip: '10.11.66.6', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Session ID: 03f8c7ca-a582-41b5-80d3-2ec53de719f5
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=37.0.1}]
```

At line number 50 i.e.

```
act.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, numOfPixels).release().perform();
```

I tried using try catch, still it is not working.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In for loop condition at number of iteration you are getting exception?

Because once the element is moved or dragged, page DOM will update and that element will not longer available to move again. That's the reason your are getting `StaleElementReferenceException`. See this explanation about [StaleElementReferenceException](http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html)

And your code to move element should be like below:

`act.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, numOfPixels).release().build().perform();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply VaraPrasad. I tried using above line of code, again getting same exception for same line of code. Please help if any other option u know.

Comment: Welcome Vrushali. But did you read my statements above about `StaleElementReferenceException`. Try to move your finding element code into for loop. `WebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-accordion-1-panel-2']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"));`

Comment: Ohhh wow...!!! Its done... Working so beautifully.... Thank you so much VaraPrasad... :D